# Trouble changing a complex sentence into a simple sentence

Tags: subordinate-clauses

How do I change this [complex
sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_clause_structure#Complex_and_compound-complex_sentences)
into a [simple sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_clause_structure#Simple_sentences)?

> He knows that time once gone is gone forever.

Comment: What makes you think you can change a sentence to a simple sentence?

Comment: It was assigned to me to change this to a simple sentence. However I find my abilities limited.

Comment: You would have to show us similar exercises and their expected answers. Otherwise we cannot know the model that the instructor is expecting you to follow. Are you sure you should produce only one simple sentence instead of one per clause from the original? Imagine how you would combine these two simple sentences into one complex one: *Spent time is forever behind us.  He knows this.*

Comment: He knows about the unstoppable nature of time.

Comment: Buck-passed to ELL? 'Return to setter' is my advice.